# Element-api search with space in query returns zero data

Tags: search, plugin-elementapi

I have an endpoint for searching entries via the element api.

```
'api/searchtherest.json' => function () {

            $section_handle = 'openFunding';

            $criteria = [
                'section' => $section_handle,
                'openForFunding' => true,
                'search' => ($q = Craft::$app->request->getParam('query'))
                    ? "-title:*\"{$q}\"*"
                    : null
            ];

            return [
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'paginate' => false,
                'pretty' => false,
                'transformer' => function (craft\elements\Entry $entry) {

                    return [
                        'id' => $entry->id,
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'localauthority' => $entry->ladnm,
                        'mapitAreaId' => $entry->mapitAreaId,
                        'fundableRegion' => $entry->fundableRegion,
                        'openForFunding' => $entry->openForFunding,
                        'geojson' => json_decode($entry->geojson),
                        'lsoacode' => $entry->lsoacode
                    ];
                },

            ];
        },
```

Because the titles have spaces i am following Brandon's advice here
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2702

But wrapping the query in quotes still produces zero data.
What am I missing?

Comment: In your query "-title:*\"{$q}\"*" try to remove the - in the start of the query, is there result still same?

Comment: That's the exclude flag - the result with or without is still no data. Weird and a real blocker

Comment: Do you get the right results searching in your control panel? As in, are things correctly indexed?

Comment: Interesting - I took the "-" not exclude flag out and cleared the element-api cache and get results with the space. So i think the question becomes how do i exclude results in an element-api search query that includes a space.....maybe a bug ?